# Boot Linux on hard disk from USB key

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

Most of the questions here are about creating a live/installation bootable USB key, but what I need is different and I can't find an answer.
I have a Linux installation on the hard drive, which, after installing Windows 10, is (obviously) not bootable. "Start with a liveCD and reinstall grub" I hear you say, but I don't want to do that: I don't want to install grub because the Linux installation is only temporary. What I need is really just a way to boot (once or twice, to run some tests) into the Linux partition. I'm pretty sure what I have to do is start from a LiveCD and enter some custom boot parameters, but I'm pretty ignorant in the matter so I have no idea what the command line should look like. Help please!

Comment: Why not use a VM to do that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I install some VM software, I then have to reinstall Linux, and this doesn't offer me anything over a LiveCD. All I want to do is test the hardware, specifically the webcam, which WIndows 10 doesn't detect (and no, I can't find drivers anywhere and Toshiba support are taking their sweet time replying). The Linux partition came with the PC (bought 2nd hand), so if the camera isn't faulty the previous owner should've installed the webcam drivers, that's why I'm keen to test THAT particular OS installation.

Comment: Ok see your situation...

Comment: Is it UEFI or BIOS? With BIOS you just need another flash drive which you still can use for data, and install grub to its MBR. If UEFI, you need the flash drive with gpt partitioning and an ESP. But will have to manually install grub and then edit/configure a grub.cfg to boot install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub makes it very easy to edit its commands, but first determine a few things on your hard disk installation. Boot the live media and :

1. Start a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t) and determine  what partition the Ubuntu installation is on and its filesystem with the blkid command.

   sudo blkid
2. Make a note of the UUID for that partition just in case the device fails to work (unlikely)
3. Mount the hard disk's Ubuntu partition, say at /mnt, and look at the boot directory for the most recent kernel (highest number) with a name like vmlinuz-3.8.0-25-generic.efi.  Note this number, you will use it in the grub edit.

Reboot the live media, and at the grub menu screen, read the instructions at the bottom.  Type "e" to edit, then using the arrow and delete keys change a few things to use the hard disk.
Change the "set root=" to be the Ubuntu's partition (probably hd0 and whatever partition you found above (for example, 7).  Your UEFI machine came with Windows so it uses GPT partitioning, so the command should be edited to:

```
set root= 'hd0,gpt7'
```

Next there are a couple of "search" commands, you can edit the items to reflect your disk and partition, or just delete them, all they do is to set the root to the UUID.  If delete doesn't work, edit them next time.  The next two lines are the ones identifying the kernel you want to boot.  Change them to the number of the kernel you found on the hard disk (probably a smaller number than is seen on the live media since the hard disk installation is old).

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-???
initrd /boot/initrd.img-???
```

With those changes, try to boot with ctrl-X or F10.  The hard disk should boot.

Answer (score -1):

I currently run Kali and Windows 10 side by side. When I did the install I hit the same problem as you. There is something with newer windwows (8 and up) and the UEFI settings that makes what your asking for not possible. (As far as I know)

If you just need Linux for a couple uses then you need to use a Live USB or CD. There is really no reason you wouldn't want to do this. If you are insistent on keeping Linux as a dual boot you will HAVE to install GRUB to manage the boot sectors. I will share the Link that I used to do this. It is for KALI but Kali and Ubuntu are both Debian and everything WILL work for you.

Remember that any roadblocks you are hitting is likely because of UEFI and not Ubuntu. It may benefit you most to research UEFI configurations.

http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows